# Cannot ssh into a computer, unless i get pinged from it

Tags: ssh, ping

I have several computers running on a local wifi. All are running ubuntu 18.04 and have static ip adresses defined in netplan. I regulary turn some of the computers on and off, and this problem occurs:

I need to ssh to a specific computer (computer 1), but for some reason I cannot ping it, nor ssh into it from my computer 2. If a take a different computer 3, which can ssh into computer 1, then ping computer 2 from computer 1, computer 2 can now ping and ssh into computer 1.

Do you know what the problem is? why computer 2 cant ssh into computer 1 right away?

Thanks.

Edit: I am using the ip adresses - ping 192.168.0.5 or ssh comp1@192.168.0.5 etc. The wifi is working, I can still access the internet through it, only the ssh and pinging does not work until I get pinged.

There is no directory encryption.

Comment: I am using the ip adresses - ping 192.168.0.5 or ssh comp1@192.168.0.5 etc.
The wifi is working, I can still access the internet through it, only the ssh and pinging does not work until I get pinged.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new information in the question.

Comment: There is no directory encryption.